# Advanced Custom Fields not working for page template

Tags: templates, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a WordPress theme that has a Homepage template and I'm using ACF for custom fields.

The ACF config is set to allow the fields for pages using the `homepage-template.php`, but for some reason the `get_field($fieldname)` is returning `NULL` and the `the_field()` doesn't show nothing, even passing the second argument `$post_id`.

This is the simple code version of the template that is not working:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Home template
 *
 * @package Package
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header();

while (have_posts()): the_post();

    the_title(); // Works

    echo get_the_ID(); // Works

    var_dump(get_field('banner-title')); // NULL

?>

<?php
  endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

- WordPress: 4.9.1
- ACF: 5.7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Debug Method:**

1. you can enable wp_debug mode in config.php
2. you can check error_log file on theme folder
3. some time your acf fieldname length has problem.
4. you can switch over theme once(back to your theme).